# Writing unit tests for constructor with shared_ptr arguments

Tags: c++, unit-testing

Should I write unit tests which verify that constructor is throwing in simple cases when a `nullptr` was provided instead of a `shared_ptr`?

Let's say I have the following class:

```
#pragma once

#include "SharedItemsListInteractorInput.hpp"
#include "SharedItemsListInteractorOutput.hpp"
#include "Store.hpp"

namespace ri {

class ItemsListInteractor : public SharedItemsListInteractorInput {
private:
    std::shared_ptr<Store> _store;
    std::shared_ptr<SharedItemsListInteractorOutput> _output;
public:
    ItemsListInteractor(
        const std::shared_ptr<Store> &store,
        const std::shared_ptr<SharedItemsListInteractorOutput> &output
    );

    void fetchItems() override;
};

}
```

Implementation:

```
#include "ItemsListInteractor.hpp"
#include <iostream>

namespace ri {

ItemsListInteractor::ItemsListInteractor(
    const std::shared_ptr<Store> &store,
    const std::shared_ptr<SharedItemsListInteractorOutput> &output
) {
    if (store == nullptr) {
        throw std::invalid_argument("Store should not be an std::nullptr");
    }
    if (output == nullptr) {
        throw std::invalid_argument("Output should not be an std::nullptr");
    }
    _store = store;
    _output = output;
}

void ItemsListInteractor::fetchItems() {
    _store->getItems(0, [=] (std::vector<SharedItem> items, bool nextPage) {
        if (_output != nullptr) {
            _output->didFetchItems(items, nextPage);
        }
    });
}

}
```

Construction tests:

```
#include "ItemsListInteractor.hpp"
#include "catch.hpp"
#include "fakeit.hpp"

using namespace Catch;
using namespace fakeit;
using namespace ri;

TEST_CASE( "items list interactor", "[ItemsListInteractor]" ) {

    SECTION( "no store" ) {
        Mock<SharedItemsListInteractorOutput> outputMock;
        Fake(Dtor(outputMock));
        auto output = std::shared_ptr<SharedItemsListInteractorOutput>(&outputMock.get());

        REQUIRE_THROWS_AS(ItemsListInteractor(nullptr, output), std::invalid_argument);
    }
    SECTION( "no output" ) {
        Mock<Store> storeMock;
        Fake(Dtor(storeMock));
        auto store = std::shared_ptr<Store>(&storeMock.get());

        REQUIRE_THROWS_AS(ItemsListInteractor(store, nullptr), std::invalid_argument);
    }
}
```

Feels like writing constructor tests, in this case, brings too much boilerplate code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Missing includes

You are missing at least:

- in the header:

  ```
    #include <memory>
  ```
- in the implementation:

  ```
    #include <exception>
  ```

## Extraneous includes

The implementation includes `<iostream>` but never uses it.  Prefer `<iosfwd>` over `<iostream>` where possible, and prefer nothing over `<iosfwd>` where possible.

## Prefer initialization to assignment

Instead of

```
_store = store;
_output = output;
```

it's better to use initializers - especially if you set your compiler to warn when you forget to initialize (recommended):

```
ItemsListInteractor::ItemsListInteractor(
    std::shared_ptr<Store> store,
    std::shared_ptr<SharedItemsListInteractorOutput> output)
  : store{std::move(store)},
    output{std::move(output)}
 {
    if (!this->store)
        throw std::invalid_argument("Store should not be null");
    if (!this->output)
        throw std::invalid_argument("Output should not be null");
}
```

I made other improvements in the above:

- pass by value, then `std::move()` in preference to passing by const ref
- name the members the same as the arguments to prevent accidental use after move from (and to be less ugly - a leading underscore shouts "*DANGER*", especially to those who also write C).
- use the (more idiomatic) `operator bool` to test the pointers' validity - this is easier to understand than comparing against a shared pointer implicitly constructed from `std::nullptr_t`.
- I changed the message - an empty shared pointer is a different type to the null pointer.

## Don't repeat the test in the method

There's no way that `output` can be assigned to, other than via the compiler-provide copy constructor and assignment operator, both of which require a valid `ItemsListInteractor`.  A valid `ItemsListInteractor` cannot have a null `output` if its constructor succeeded.

```
void ItemsListInteractor::fetchItems() {
    store->getItems(0, [=](std::vector<SharedItem> items, bool nextPage) {
        output->didFetchItems(items, nextPage);
    });
}
```

## Tests

The tests look adequate, as far as they go.  The `fetchItems()` method should also be tested.

Comment: @TobySpeight thank you. I am actually compiling my project without those inclusions. Your constructor updates are valuable for me. Question about "Don't repeat the test": what if shared_ptr becomes null over time? I am using a complex cross-platform environment and it happens a lot. It actually means that shared_ptr behaves more like a weak_ptr, but I can't control that and can't use weak_ptr.`fetchItems()` is tested in another file.

Comment: Then you've broken the implicit contract set in your constructor, @asdf. Check your (implicit) specification whether the `shared_ptr` might become null over time?

Comment: @TobySpeight did the way you implemented constructor change semantics of original class? In your version ref count is increased when you pass a pointer, in my, it is not? Am I right?

Comment: In my version the ref-count is increased slightly earlier (when the constructor is called, rather than when the member is assigned within the constructor).  That does mean that if the constructor throws, there will be slightly more work (the refcount will be decremented again as the construction is unwound) - but that's pretty insignificant against the cost of throwing.  None of this changes the semantics at all - the object still owns copies of the shared pointers.

Comment: @TobySpeight But did my original constructor incremented ref counter correctly? I am reading about passing a shared_ptr by reference and they say that such approach doesn't transfer ownership. I thought that my original code was erroneous in this case?

Comment: @TobySpeight at the same time I am reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3310737/shared-ptr-by-reference-or-by-value/8741626#8741626 "never pass by value" unless you have issues with multithreading code.

Comment: @TobySpeight also "Use a const shared_ptr& as a parameter only if you’re not sure whether or not you’ll take a copy and share ownership;"  https://stackoverflow.com/a/26197326/83938 Could you enlighten me a bit?

Comment: There's not much context in the linked answer, but it seems to only address the case where the shared pointer is merely *used* and not *copied*, by the function.  Here, we copy into a member, and it's usually more appropriate to pass by value in this case (as we *know* that a copy will be taken) and `std::move()` to the member.  This allows the caller to `std::move()` from an lvalue, or to pass an rvalue, more efficiently.

Comment: @TobySpeight which compiler did you use? Which one demanded to include memory and exception explicitly?

Comment: I usually use GCC.  Don't rely on compilers to diagnose missing headers - they are allowed to transitively include more than the standard requires, so absence of a warning does not indicate absence of a problem.